# Отрисовка флага в Photoshop

Tags: photoshop

Возможно, кто-то стыкался с подобными задачами. Как из обычного флага сделать такой:

[image]

Comment: вот нашел что-то похожее на правду. http://youtu.be/godOxTxBsOY

Comment: @dekameron, [оставшаяся часть вопроса][1], как я посмотрел, не проблема

   [1]:http://tinyurl.com/q8k49u5

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)